# Python Pandas Dataframe - Best Join and filter condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-merge

Input:

| Dt | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/2/22 | X | Y |
| 2/2/22 | Y | X |
| 2/2/22 | X | Y |
| 2/2/22 | A | B |
| 2/2/22 | P | Q |
| 2/3/22 | Q | P |
| 2/2/22 | C | D |
| 2/3/22 | Y | X |

Output:

| Dt | From | To | Dt | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/2/22 | X | Y | 2/2/22 | Y | X |
| 2/2/22 | X | Y | 2/3/22 | Y | X |
| 2/2/22 | P | Q | 2/3/22 | Q | P |

Note:
4th and 7th row is ignored as there is no counterparts.
Each row should join with their counterparts only once.
Join should happen for the same day and the following day only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[::2, :].reset_index(drop = True), df.iloc[1::2, :].reset_index(drop = True)], axis = 1)
```

Output -

|  | Dt | From | To | Dt | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2/2/22 | X | Y | 2/2/22 | Y | X |
| 1 | 2/2/22 | X | Y | 2/3/22 | Y | X |

Comment: If I had data across multiple days  and unsorted, this might not work. Would merging on DT:DT/DT:DT+1, FROM:TO, TO:FROM help better, we will have to then exclude the double joins. I have added more example on the question

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.merge(df, left_on=['From', 'To'], right_on=['To', 'From'])
df2[df2.Dt_x < df2.Dt_y] 
# Or, we could be more exact if they were proper datetimes:
# df2[df2.Dt_x == (df2.Dt_y - pd.Timedelta(days=1))
```

Output:

```
     Dt_x From_x To_x    Dt_y From_y To_y
1  2/2/22      X    Y  2/3/22      Y    X
3  2/2/22      X    Y  2/3/22      Y    X
8  2/2/22      P    Q  2/3/22      Q    P
```